# New to Android Studio , Splash Screen Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, splash-screen

I am new to Android Studio and to the OS and have been designing an application, I tried to add a splash screen to my application after creating the splash screen and adding it to my manifest file but I keep getting this error:

> Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error
>   while Launching activity

The tutorial I followed to get the splash screen provides no insight to correcting this error.

Below is my entire manifest file if someone could correct me I would be grateful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gui.prog">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Display" ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Signup" ></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: wrong intent filter used, use it under splash actvity

Answer (score 3):

Just copy paste file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Display" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Signup" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

It will work, as currently it is unable to know which activity is initial one.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do for a 'SplashActivity' is set my 'MainActivity' as a regular activity, and set my 'SplashActivity' as the default activity that will begin on launch.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".Splash">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity> 
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" ></activity>
```

Then in my SplashActivity's 'onCreate' method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: you my Friend are a LifeSaver fixed my problem thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you cant put two intent filters in the android manifest file if you want to launch app with spalsh screen activity you have to put the intent filter in the splash activity